What is the expected way to specify an image pull secret in Kubeflow?
I have generated the secret, but cannot configure it in kubeflow's implementation.
If I look in kfp, I see that all references to imagePull are in the deprecated folder:
$ grep -rn 'imagePull' kfp/

./kfp/deprecated/compiler/compiler.py:851:            workflow['spec']['imagePullSecrets'] = image_pull_secrets
./kfp/deprecated/compiler/compiler.py:875:                    if container and "imagePullPolicy" not in container:
./kfp/deprecated/compiler/compiler.py:877:                            "imagePullPolicy"] = pipeline_conf.image_pull_policy
./kfp/deprecated/compiler/compiler.py:880:                    'Invalid imagePullPolicy. Must be one of `Always`, `Never`, `IfNotPresent`.'
./kfp/deprecated/dsl/_container_op.py:526:                'Invalid imagePullPolicy. Must be one of `Always`, `Never`, `IfNotPresent`.'
./kfp/deprecated/dsl/_container_op.py:1183:        # set `imagePullPolicy` property for `container` with `PipelineParam`

If it is deprecated, I am guessing there is some expected way for me to hand over the secret to Kubeflow.  However, I cannot find much documentation.
Note that this is for a local deployment -- the objective is to see things working.  On the other hand, I have ChatGPT telling me to 'patch' the kubeflow deployment with a service account that has the secrets. This feels a bit hand-wavy, and I am disconnected from whatever magic is going to actually make things work.

What is the new expected way for us to specify imagePullSecrets for an implementation container in the implementation yaml file? Or, barring that, what is the expected way to grant a local deployment of kubeflow access to a registry?

In new version you find solution with set_image_pull_secrets from kfp-kubernetes package.
pip install kfp-kubernetes 

kfp-kubernetes
or
pip install kfp[all]

Create your kubernetes secrets for custom docker registry
kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret_name> --docker-server=<custom-docker-reg-url> --docker-username=<your_docker_user_name> --docker-password=<your_docker_password> --docker-email=<your_docker_email>

Then you can set the imagePullSecrets
from kfp import kubernetes
kubernetes.set_image_pull_secrets(<your-task>, [<your-secret-name>])

There were some issues in using this. Please see the issue here
set_image_pull_secrets
Another method is patch your secretes with your default service-account
kubectl patch serviceaccount <your-default-serviceaccount> -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "<secret_name>"}]}'

